# How does WordPress differentiate what scripts are loaded in wp_head() and wp_footer()?

Tags: php

A newbie question. I have gone through the `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` documentation and both are said to be including the scripts and styles. So my question is how does WordPress differentiate which scripts need to be in the `wp_head()` and which needs to be in `wp_footer()`.
My understanding is that the `wp_head()` will include all the scripts and styles in the header section of the webpage, and calling the `wp_footer()` will again include the same scripts and styles in the footer section of the website. I know it is wrong.

Comment: scripts are loaded whereever the wp_scripts() or wp_script() is loaded I guess, they're not part of wp_head or wp_footer, sorry I've forgotten the exact function name, I think it's wp_scripts

Comment: Read through this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ There’s a parameter $in_footer

Comment: I don't understand why there is a down-vote for question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) has a parameter which specifies if the script should be rendered in `wp_head` or `wp_footer`

The function signature is this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

Note that it is the **5th** parameter, so if you wish to not have any dependencies and use the default version number for your script you still have to supply those parameters. For example:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'your_script_name', 'your_script_location', array(),false, true );
                                                                                ^     
                        //  This will cause the script to render in wp_footer   |
```